# getting data from DFs to put into a main DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get data from a list of dfs into one df.

I am using the following code

```
main_df =  pd.DataFrame(columns=data.columns[-len_data+1:], index = is_refs)
for index, dict in enumerate(dict_lists):
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_lists[index])
    df = df.reindex(is_refs)
    main_df = main_df.append(df[df.columns])
```

The problem is that it returns the following DF. Clearly I don't want repeated items in the index and just want the financial data to fit into my rows. Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df_col = df[df.columns]
print(df_col)
main_df = main_df.join(df_col)
```